# unable to send email from android application on real device

Tags: android

I developed an application which sends an email. While running it on device, it shows the message "Message Sending...." but the email is not actually sent.

Here is my code:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});

email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
email.setType("plain/text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Sending mail..."));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String []mailto = { "Your emill id"};
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,mailto);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "MySendMail"));
```

and 
in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using intents, they are not supposed to send the email but launch any email client installed on the device.

Android will automatically filter application that say they can send plain/text and prompt the user which app he wants to use.

But then, depending on the app the user finally choose, the user will have a chance to review the mail and other stuff before sending it.

If you only want to send the email then you will have to implement your own email client (there are plenty java email libs available) or use an explicit intent (instead of implicit you are using right now) to an app you know directly send the email.

I hope im clear enough

More informations on the official doc : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html